# Notation in Fundamental Groups in Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology, notation, fundamental-groups

I was reading about [Fundamental Groups in Topological Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group) at WikiPedia. In the middle of the text, they define the following set $\pi_1(X,x_0):$

---

[image]

---

I guess I don't understand the meaning of *"*$\text{/homotopy}$*"*. What does this mean?

Comment: You're really going to have to find a good textbook on this if you actually want to learn about it.

Comment: @Tyrone Yes, definitely. However, I'm preparing for the exam that is going to be tomorrow, so I must have some quick image about it to represent tomorrow :)

Comment: If $A$ is a set and $\sim$ an equivalence relation in $A$, you know what $A/\!\sim$ means?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a set $S$ and an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S$, then
$$S / \sim$$
denotes the set of all equivalence classes with respect to $\sim $. In your question we have $S =$ set of all loops $\gamma : [0,1] \to X$ based at $x_0$. You have the relation *$\gamma$ is homotopic to $\gamma'$* which is an equivalence relation on $S$. If you write $\gamma \simeq \gamma'$ for this equivalence relation, then
$$\pi_1(X,x_0) = S/\simeq \phantom{.}= S/\text{homotopy} .$$